# Getting data from multi-dimensional array with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to find out why I am not able to get the single values of each array of items individually every 3 seconds.

As you can see I am getting entire array values instead of getting them individually. What I need it to get then individually and console log of ending each level of first level array

```js
var imgs = [
  [
    ['#fff', '#eee'],
    ['#117A65', '#E74C3C'],
    ['#F39C12', '#AF7AC5']
  ],
  [
    ['#7B241C  ', '#eee'],
    ['#117A65', '#909497  ']
  ],
  [
    ['#17A589', '#626567']
  ],
  [
    ['#5499C7', '#eee'],
    ['#117A65', '#884EA0']
  ],
];
for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < imgs[i].length; j++) {
    for (let b = 0; b < imgs[j].length; b++) {
      (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(imgs[i][j][b]);
        }, i * 3000);
      })(i);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `flat` the array and use one loop:

```js
var imgs=[[['#fff','#eee'],['#117A65','#E74C3C'],['#F39C12','#AF7AC5']],[['#7B241C  ','#eee'],['#117A65','#909497  ']],[['#17A589','#626567']],[['#5499C7','#eee'],['#117A65','#884EA0']]];

const flattened = imgs.flat(2);

for (let i = 0; i < flattened.length; i++) {
  console.log(flattened[i]);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to do something after each first-level iteration, you should go with a classic `for` loop:

```js
var imgs=[[['#fff','#eee'],['#117A65','#E74C3C'],['#F39C12','#AF7AC5']],[['#7B241C  ','#eee'],['#117A65','#909497  ']],[['#17A589','#626567']],[['#5499C7','#eee'],['#117A65','#884EA0']]];

for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < imgs[i].length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < imgs[i][j].length; k++) {
      console.log(imgs[i][j][k]);
    }
  }
  console.log("First level iteration complete - callback here!");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, this is good but How can I notice the completion of each first level array? I mean I need to do some call back after finishing the first array and so on. by this way there is no way to achieve this

Comment: So @MonaCoder, first level array right? So once `#fff #eee...#AF7AC5` has been logged, you should be able to do something, correct?

Comment: Exaclty and I need to do this after ending all first levels

Comment: OK @MonaCoder, how's that?